# Display all data of JSON

Tags: javascript

I have JSON like this:

```
let a = 

    {
      "name": "rahul",
      "age": "25"
    }
```

I want to display all the data from this JSON.
So I was doing like this:

```
<div>{a.name}</div>
<div>{a.age}</div>
```

But not the data in json can be different also.

So I want to display all the data (Data in json can be dynamic that is sometimes there can be 2 values sometimes 5 values)

Comment: Hello, 
Is this react?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(jsonVar)`

Comment: I think that you will need to use Javascript to print data inside div also I recommend to use `<h1>` instead of `<div>`.

Comment: and if you want to iterate then use keys = Object.keys(jsonVar). and then loop on keys to get values and format accordingly. Can you specify which js framework you are using and  a example of the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the brackets I'm assuming that you're using react.

You can use the Object.keys()  method to get an array containing the keys of your object and simply iterate through that.

```js
const data = {
  name: "John",
  age: 24,
  birthday: "01/23/2020",
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(data).map((key) => (
        <p>
          {key}: {data[key]}
        </p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I will try something like :

```
let str = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(str)
```

You may checkout [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from those brackets you are using react:

You can use `Object.values` to get the values, and then loop them.

If you want the keys as well you can use `Object.keys`.

```js
const Example = () => {

  let a = {
      "name": "rahul",
      "age": "25",
      "phoneNumber": 1234566,
    }


  return ( 
    <div>
      <p><strong>Using Object.values:</strong></p>
      {Object.values(a).map(value => (<div>{value}</div>))}
      
      <p><strong>Using Object.keys:</strong></p>
      {Object.keys(a).map(key => (<div>{key} : {a[key]}</div>))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <Example /> ,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this :

```
var template = '';
Object.values(a).map(item => {

    template +='<div>' + item + '</div>';
});
```

You can use template in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just have a javascript tag, so for normal html with javascript, looping json and appending div will do the trick.

```js
let a = {
      "name": "rahul",
      "age": "25",
        "gender":"male"
}

for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var node = document.createElement("div");
        node.innerHTML = a[key];
        document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="parent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```